# When can one omit "that" from a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

In general, when can I omit *that* from a sentence?

Can I omit *that* (emphasized) in sentence (2) below?

> 1. We say **that** such algorithms handle concept drift and can learn from time-changing data streams.
> 2. When the statistical properties of the target variable change, we say **that** concept drift has occurred.
> 3. She told me **that** some of her classmates failed.

To me, sentences (1) and (3) sound better without *that*. If I omit *that* from (2), it just doesn't sound right when I read it out loud. (I should point out I'm not a native speaker.)

How do **you** decide when to omit it? Is it just a matter of taste? (I know *that* is sometimes mandatory.)

Can you think of sentences that "sound better" with *that*? Can you think of sentences that "sound better" without *that*? Can you think of a few sentences where it is wrong to omit *that*?

Comment: All three of your examples use a "that" which is a marker of clausal subordination: in your case, that "that" marks the beginning of a *declarative content clause*. Sometimes that "that" marker is obligatory, sometimes optional, sometimes not allowed. There are some related rules on this, but there is no one simple general rule. It's something that native English speakers just pick up while speaking and listening and reading. (Note: Your "that" is NOT a relative word or relative pronoun.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three of your examples use a "that" which is a **marker of clausal subordination:** in your case, that "that" marks the beginning of a **declarative content clause.**

Sometimes that "that" marker is obligatory, sometimes optional, sometimes not allowed. There are some related rules on this, but there is no one simple general rule. It's something that native English speakers just pick up while speaking and listening and reading.

Note: Your "that" is NOT a relative word or relative pronoun. (There is another "that" which is the marker of clausal subordination for *that*-relative clauses. Some grammars consider that the two markers to be, or could be considered to be, the same. In any case, the "that" marker for relative clauses has a different set of rules in regard to its presence or absence than the one marking declarative content clauses.)

One rather firm rule--well, somewhat a firm "rule"--is that if the declarative content clause is the subject of the main clause, then the "that" marker is obligatory. That is so the reader will get a heads-up to realize that the content clause's subject is NOT the subject of the main clause, even though it is located at the beginning of the sentence.

There are a whole bunch of more similar rules, but they are all rather specific as to the syntactic situation that they are talking about. If the rules were simplified or made too general, then there would be too many so-called exceptions. Native English speakers know these rules implicitly (their ear does all the work), but they would usually be hard pressed to explain them--and if they attempted to explain them, their explanations would often be wrong and/or misleading.

Answer (score 0):

They are fine. And, as you say, it is preference. I like to think of the word *that* as a light bulb, using it only when there isn't enough clarity. Some examples:

1. "She said *that* the criminal could not be found." - It's not really necessary, even though it sounds a little weird without it.
2. "It was when she heard footprints in the night *that* she decided to call the police." - You probably should leave *that* where it is.
3. "I hate sentences *that* end with a preposition."- It's best to use *that* here.

It doesn't hurt if you choose to use it. And there are usually ways around using it. But you're right — sometimes you must use it, although I find those cases to be rare. Personally, I rework sentences so *that* isn't used because, as a reader, I hate to trip over unnecessary words. Just my two cents. (: -MP

Comment: Your third example is a relative clause, not a complement clause; as such, it is not really relevant to the question at hand. (In relative clauses, _that_ is mandatory when it marks the subject, optional otherwise; in complement clauses, things are far more complicated.)

Comment: Hm, I see! Thank you for the clarification and correction. I figured it would be worth showing the general uses of "that". I wasn't aware that we were only focusing on complement clauses (my apologies to the OP).

Answer (score 0):

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p584) has a section on when *that* can be omitted. He notes that while *that* is omitted after many common reporting verbs, there are "*certain verbs, especially intransitive verbs*" after which that "*cannot be dropped*". His examples are *reply*, *email*, *shout*:

> ? James replied he was feeling better.
>
> ? She shouted she was busy.

Note that in my sentence above (and in this one) *that* cannot be dropped:

> ? He notes while that is omitted after many common reporting verbs,
>   there are "certain verbs ...

Swan also says: "*That is not usually dropped after nouns.*"

> ? I did not believe his claim he was ill.
>
> ? He disagreed with Copernicus' view the earth went around the sun.

Comment: I definitely don’t agree with Swan about the first two. “James replied he was feeling better” and “She shouted she was busy” are both perfectly natural and idiomatic to me—no need for a question mark at all. _Note_, however, does require _that_, as do nouns.

Comment: @Janus. For me _reply_ and _shout_ lie on a continuum of reporting verbs between those where omitting _that_ is common and natural and those where the omission sounds questionable. Example: _?He observed all research is now conducted in universities_. Native-speakers will inevitably locate these verbs at different places along the continuum.

Answer (score -1):

I love **William Strunk**, *The Elements of Style*. In response to your first question about omitting *that* from a sentence, here are *some* of his brilliant suggestions:

> In especial the expression *the fact that* should be revised out of:

1. owing to the fact that  -- replace with *since*
2. (because) in spite of the fact that --- replace with *though (although)*
3. call your attention to the fact that     -- *remind you (notify you)*