# "Realized" vs "Realized that "

Tags: grammar

I believe this is a syntax question. I'm sorry if this is the wrong tag.

Which is correct?

1. Through my education, volunteer work, and work experience, I have truly **realized** Tagore was right, service is joy.
2. Through my education, volunteer work, and work experience, I have truly **realized that** Tagore was right, service is joy.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can one omit "that" from a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170112/when-can-one-omit-that-from-a-sentence) FE's _answer_ gives the general answer, and the later analysis from Swan (in Shoe's _answer_) does not include _realise_ as one of the verbs after which the complementiser _that_ must not be dropped. It is optional here, though I'd say advisable given the weightiness of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. *That* may be needed for clarity with some other verbs. For example, "I heard Tagore was right" is grammatically correct, but until the reader gets to the fourth word (*was*) it's not obvious that the object of *heard* is not *Tagore* but the whole clause "Tagore was right." For the first three words, the sentence seems to be saying, "I heard Tagore," but the intended meaning is different. "I heard that Tagore was right" is unambiguous.